# Zend Framework 1 - How to detect routing errors from within a plugin at routeShutdown

Tags: zend-framework, plugins

Zend Framework 1.11.11

I am writing a Zend Framework Controller Plugin that does stuff in the `routeShutdown` hook.

I'd like to be able to avoid running my processes if there are routing errors.

i.e. I do not want to run the processes if we are just gonna get a 404 error.

```
class MyPlugin extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
    {


    public function routeShutdown( Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $zfRequestObj )
        {

        if ( $this->isRoutingError() )
            {
            //there was a routing error do not do any intensive page start up stuff
            return;
            }

        return $this->doRouteShutdownProcesses( $zfRequestObj );                
        }

    protected function isRoutingError()
            {
            //?? So how do we get this?
            }
    ...

    }
```

**So, how can we determine if there was a routing error at this point?**

Things I have tried.

- Check the module, controller, action name in the requestObj

  - Does not work cos that is not set to Error Action yet
- Check for exceptions in response object

  - Does not work cos `$this->getResponse()->isException()` seems to return FALSE, even when there was a routing error.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have worked it out myself.

I was being stupid. At routeShutdown we do not know whether its going to be a 404 page type error until we try to dispatch it.

So all we can do is

- test for general exceptions in the response
- ask the dispatcher if the route is likely to be Dispatchable.

So the plugin cannot really determine if there is a 'routing error' - so it has to ask "isRouteShutdownToBeSkipped()" :

```
<?php

class MyPlugin extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
    {


    public function routeShutdown( Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $zfRequestObj )
        {

        if ( $this->isRouteShutdownToBeSkipped( $zfRequestObj ) )
            {
            //do not do any intensive page start up stuff
            return;
            }

        return $this->doRouteShutdownProcesses( $zfRequestObj );                
        }

    //...
```

Then the isRouteShutdownToBeSkipped() method tests for

- general exceptions, or for
- undispatchable controllers
- action methods that do not exist. (I avoid using magic in my project, so I know that if the method aint declared, then it aint gonna work.)

So:

```
<?php

class MyPlugin extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
    {

    //...

    protected function isRouteShutdownToBeSkipped( Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $zfRequestObj )
        {   

        if ( $this->getResponse()->isException() )
            {
            //Skip cos there was an exception already.
            return TRUE;
            }

        if (!( $this->isDispatchable( $zfRequestObj ) )) 
            {
            //Skip cos route is not dispatchable (i.e no valid controller found).
            return TRUE;
            }


        if (!( $this->actionMethodExists( $zfRequestObj ) ))
            {
            //There is no action method on the controller class that 
            //resembles the requested action.
            return TRUE;
            }

        //else else give it a go
        return FALSE;
        }
    //...
```

My `isDispatchable()` method simply delegates to the dispatcher:

```
<?php

class MyPlugin extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
    {

    //...

    protected function isDispatchable( Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $zfRequestObj )
        {
        return Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()
            ->getDispatcher()
            ->isDispatchable( $zfRequestObj );      
        }
    ...
```

My `actionMethodExists()` method is a little bit more complex. The dispatcher's interface is a bit misleading (`getControllerClass()` does not actually return a classname), so we have to jump through some hoops to get the actual controller class name, then load the class in time for the call to PHP's builtin `method_exists()` function:

```
<?php    
class MyPlugin extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
    {    
    //...

    /**
    * @desc 
    * @returns boolean - TRUE if action method exists
    */
    protected function actionMethodExists( Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $zfRequestObj )
        {

        //getControllerClass() does not return the module prefix
        $controllerClassSuffix = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()
            ->getDispatcher()
            ->getControllerClass( $zfRequestObj );


        $controllerClassName = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()
            ->getDispatcher()
            ->formatClassName( $zfRequestObj->getModuleName() , $controllerClassSuffix );


        //load the class before we call method_exists()
        Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()
            ->getDispatcher()
            ->loadClass( $controllerClassSuffix );

        $actionMethod = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()
            ->getDispatcher()
            ->getActionMethod( $zfRequestObj );

        return ( method_exists( $controllerClassName, $actionMethod ) );
        }

    //...

    }
```

Comment: No problem. I'm glad that you found it useful.